# Is there a way to remove numbers from the end of module names?

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have some code that imports modules, but on doing so it will add a number to the end of the name. Is there a way to remove the numbers from the names on import?

```
Sub ImportModules()
Dim wkbTarget As Excel.Workbook
Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As Scripting.File
Dim szTargetWorkbook As String
Dim szImportPath As String
Dim cmpComponents As VBIDE.VBComponents
Dim SpecialPath As String

oneback = Left(ThisWorkbook.path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.path, "\") - 1)

SpecialPath = oneback & "\" & Range("PathToModule")
'^ Path where the code modules are located.


'Get the path to the folder with modules
If SpecialPath = "Error" Then
    MsgBox "Import Folder not exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Excel.
szTargetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set wkbTarget = Application.Workbooks(szTargetWorkbook)

Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
If objFSO.GetFolder(SpecialPath).Files.Count = 0 Then
   MsgBox "There are no files to import"
   Exit Sub
End If

Set cmpComponents = wkbTarget.VBProject.VBComponents

Dim cell As Range
Dim rng

Set rng = Range("ModuleName")

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(SpecialPath).Files
    For Each cell In rng
    'If objFile.Name Like "*Import*" Then GoTo skipImport ' Skips the Import Module
    If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "bas" And _
        objFile.Name = cell And _
        objFile.DateLastModified > cell.Offset(0, 1) Then
        Debug.Print cell

        Dim CurrentModuleName

        CurrentModuleName = Left(objFile.Name, (InStrRev(objFile.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
        '^ Gets the file name of the module being imported and removes the extension

        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(CurrentModuleName)
        VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
        '^ Removes the module that is to be replaced

        cell.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " " & Format(Time, "hh.nn.ss")
        '^ Keep time as without, it will import the same module throughout the day when opened.

        cmpComponents.Import objFile.path
    End If

Next cell
Next objFile

End Sub
```

When it get to the cmpComponents.Import section, it duplicate the module and then when the code has finish. It leaves the module with the number at the end, deleting the one it has replaced

Comment: Please show the code that imports.  What does the name look like before import? and after import?  Will I get the same result when I duplicate the code and run it on my machine?

Comment: Hi, say the module is called exam, it should delete exam and then import the updated file. But it imports first calling it exam1 and then deletes exam. I have found out that this happens only when i open the wookbook as the code runs on open. If i run it when the wookbook is already open, then the module gets replaced as it should do.

Comment: Please show the code that is being run upon open, and show how it does the import and then the delete.  Perhaps it does NOT call the sub  ImportModules but does something else inline.

Comment: Range("PathToModule") is not defined.  What code defines this?